# Density and convergence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a small question:

Is it true that if 
the basis of a space $A$ is dense in a space $B$ ($B\subset A$)

then if $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $A$ we have that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $B$ ?

Comment: and if we have a sub sequence $(u_{n_k})$ such that $u_{n_k}$ converge weakly to $u$ in $B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $A=L_2(S^1)$, B=$W_2^1(S^1)$, and basis=$\{e^{ik\phi}\}_{k=-\infty}^\infty$ (where $\phi\mod 2\pi$ is the coordinate on $S^1$). This basis is dense in $B$, but the $L^2$-convergence does not imply convergence in the Sobolev space $W_2^1$.

Comment: Ok, so please what is the use of density in Brezis page 231 he consider an operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$ and he proves that it's compact and he sayes that we can consider this operator fron $H^1_0$to $H^1_0$ using the density of $L^2$ on $H^1_0$

Comment: I do not have that book in my library; sorry.

Comment: but please what is the purpes on Density it gives an isomorphisme or what ?

Comment: No it does not. By the way, $L^2$ is not dense in $H_0^1$, it is the other way round: $H_0^1$ is dense in $L^2$. The only use of "density" I can think of is as follows: if a sequence $u_n\in B\subset A$ converges to $u$ in $A$ and to $v$ in $B$, then $u\in B$ and $u=v$.

Comment: he proves that the basis of $L^2$ is dense in $H^1_0$

Comment: This is not true; maybe you mean the linear span of a basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15708/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-vladimir).